# 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED) while searching for htmlelement

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find the submit button on a page and submit the form using webbrowser and this part of the code keeps giving me

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

the code is:

```
     HtmlDocument pagehtml = this.webBrowser1.Document;
     HtmlElementCollection page = pagehtml.All;

                foreach (HtmlElement element in page)
                {
                    if (element.GetAttribute("type") == "submit") //line that is highlighted during the error
                    {
                        element.InvokeMember("click");
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure why it was doing that but I found a different way to do it

```
                HtmlElementCollection page = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
                foreach (HtmlElement element in page)
                {
                    if (element.GetAttribute("value").Contains("Submit"))
                    {
                        element.InvokeMember("click");
                    }
                }
```